# How to use tabletop by python-docx

Tags: python-docx, tabstop

I'm new to python-docx and I want to align both left indent and right indent in one line. But I cannot find an example to show how to do it. Could someone help me?

I want to add one line for company and job title, like "Google  Engineer", I want "Google" to be aligned to left indent and "Engineer" to right indent in one line. How can I do this in python-docx by add tabstop in paragraph_format?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can resolve that exactly by adding tab stops.

If you look at the picture bellow, firstly you'll need to calculate where to a add tab stop. If you want to make *Engineer* aligned to the right within the same line(paragraph), then you need to calculate endpoint based on page width and left/right margins.

[image]

Then once you have that, it's important that you set `WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT` while adding tab stop, which is going to make sure that content is right-aligned and that it "sticks" to the right side.

Here's example code for your case:

```py
import docx
doc = docx.Document()

p = doc.add_paragraph('Google\tEngineer')  # tab will trigger tabstop
sec = doc.sections[0]
# finding end_point for the content 
margin_end = docx.shared.Inches(
    sec.page_width.inches - (sec.left_margin.inches + sec.right_margin.inches))
tab_stops = p.paragraph_format.tab_stops
# adding new tab stop, to the end point, and making sure that it's `RIGHT` aligned.
tab_stops.add_tab_stop(margin_end, docx.enum.text.WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT)

doc.save("test.docx")
```